# How to fadeTo() everything except one div?

Tags: jquery, fadeto

I am creating a tutorial and want to fade every div on the page apart from the div I want them to see. How can I do this using fadeTo?

I currently have it set to fade the whole body. How can I set it to fade the body apart from div id "step2"?

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("body").fadeTo("slow", 0.5, function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing your HTML, but if `step2` is a child of `<body>` you could do this:

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/SS5Sm/

```
$("body").children(':not(#step2)').fadeTo("slow", 0.5, function() {
  // Animation complete.
});
```

or

```
$("body > :not(#step2)").fadeTo("slow", 0.5, function() {
  // Animation complete.
});
```

If it is more deeply nested, you could try this.

```
$("body > :not(:has(#step2))").fadeTo("slow", 0.5, function() {
  // Animation complete.
});​
```

Although it makes some additional assumptions about your HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for the [not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

A fade will always fade every element under and including the one you selected with jQuery. Unless the div you want to stay visible is directly under the body, this will be tricky. To achieve the effect you desire, you should clone the div you want visible, and absolutely position it in the same location as the original. That also means you'll need to put the main content that is getting hidden inside of a container div, so instead of fading the body, fade the container div, and put the cloned div at the top level directly under the body, after the container.

```
<body>
    <div id="content-to-fade">
        ...<div id="div-i-want-">...</div>
    </div>
    <div id="copy-of-div-i-want">...</div>
</body>
```

so in the example, you would create "copy-of-div-i-want", append to the body and then call fadeTo on "content-to-fade".

This technique is a pretty common way of implementing drag and drop, because the copy can easily and efficiently be absolutely positioned around the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use css-selectors with JQuery :)

```
$("*:not(div#step2)").fadeTo(...)
```

Comment: **never ever use the universal selector (*). NEVER NEVER NEVER !**

Comment: This would individually queue a fade animation for every element, probably crashing IE instantly :)

Comment: Using `"body :not(div#step2)"` instead of `"*:not(div#step2)"` will only skip two iterations (`html` and `body`) since `":not(...)"` is just shorthand for `"*:not(...)"`. Thus making it just as fast (or slow) as the provided solution (given that `div#step2` probably isn't a direct child of `body`). In any case, I think you shouldn't use the `:not(...)`-selector in the first place, since it always means you lost track of your elements and are trying to fix that by using a css selector not really meant for production use.

Answer (score 0):

It is basically impossible to do what you've described with the code you gave, because all elements have to be contained within the body tag, and since the `opacity` property inherits, *everything* on the page will turn half transparent. Oh, and overriding the `opacity` property on that single `div` also won't work.

Instead, what you need to do is probably to move everything to another `div`, and fade that one instead. Using the `:not` selector may also work, but it isn't a catchall solution - be aware of your page structure.